# Creating own .obj exporter for maya

Tags: python, mesh, maya, pymel

I am creating my own .obj exporter for maya.

When i'm exporting just one mesh my code works just fine but when exporting several meshes / objects it fails to create the complete meshes.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is when i'm getting the 
face.getVertices(), face.getUVIndex() and face.normalIndex() and printing them to the file. As i said the first mesh works fine but when it gets to the second mesh the codinates gets all wrong, they connect to the wrong triangles. 
If anyone has any ideas on how to possibly loop them differently or change the values to the correct ones i would be forever greatful. Help would be very very appreciated!

Here is an example on how a multi object mesh ends out.
http://postimg.org/image/rr0fvs0v7/

```
import pymel.core as pm
import pymel.core.nodetypes as nt

planes = pm.ls(sl=True)

def meshFile():    
    def myRound(n):
        return round(n, 6)

    file = open("C:/Users/Blondiegirls/Desktop/test2.obj", "wb")
    file.write("mtllib test2.mtl\r\n")
    for p in planes[:]:
        #pm.polyTriangulate(planes[0])
        file.write("\r\ng default")

        # Printa world kordinater
        for index, point in enumerate(p.vtx):
            temp = index,map(myRound, point.getPosition(space='world'))

            file.write("\r\nv ")
            file.write(str(' '.join(map(str, temp[1]))))

        # Printa texture kordinater
        mesh = pm.ls(g=True)[0]
        U,V = mesh.getUVs()
        UVs = zip(U,V)
        for uv in UVs:
            file.write("\r\nvt ")
            file.write(str(uv[0])+" "+str(uv[1]))

        #printa normals
        for n in p.getNormals():
            file.write("\r\nvn ")
            file.write(str(n[0])+" "+str(n[1])+" "+str(n[2]))

        file.write("\r\ns 1")    
        file.write("\r\ng ")
        file.write(str(p))
        file.write("\r\nusemtl test")
        for faceIndex, face in enumerate(p.faces):
            faceVertices = face.getVertices()
            faceUV0 = face.getUVIndex(0)+1
            faceUV1 = face.getUVIndex(1)+1
            faceUV2 = face.getUVIndex(2)+1

            faceNor0 = face.normalIndex(0)+1
            faceNor1 = face.normalIndex(1)+1
            faceNor2 = face.normalIndex(2)+1


            file.write("\r\nf ")
            faceVertices0 = int(faceVertices[0])+1
            faceVertices1 = int(faceVertices[1])+1
            faceVertices2 = int(faceVertices[2])+1
            temp3 = (str(faceVertices0)) + "/" + (str(faceUV0)) +"/" + (str(faceNor0)) + " " + (str(faceVertices1)) + "/" + (str(faceUV1)) +"/" + (str(faceNor1)) + " " + (str(faceVertices2)) + "/" + (str(faceUV2)) +"/" + (str(faceNor2))         
            file.write(str(temp3))
    file.close()

meshFile()   


def MTLFile():
    file2 = open("C:/Users/Blondiegirls/Desktop/test2.mtl", "wb")

    object = cmds.ls(sl=1)[0].split(':')[0]
    #print('object: '+object)

    shipTX = pm.PyNode(object)
    shadingGroups = shipTX.shadingGroups()
    sg1 = shadingGroups[0]

    material = sg1.listConnections(source=True, destination=False, type=nt.Lambert)[0]
    file = material.color.listConnections(type=nt.File)[0]
    filename = file.fileTextureName.get()

    materialColor = material.getColor() #for Kd
    materialAmbient = material.getAmbientColor() #for Ka
    materialSpecular = material.getSpecularColor() #for Ks
    refractiveIndex = material.getRefractiveIndex() #for Ni

    file2.write("newmtl "+"test"+"\r\n")
    file2.write("Ka "+str(materialAmbient[0])+" "+str(materialAmbient[1])+" "+str(materialAmbient[2])+"\r\n")
    file2.write("Kd "+str(materialColor[0])+" "+str(materialColor[1])+" "+str(materialColor[2])+"\r\n")
    file2.write("Ks "+str(materialSpecular[0])+" "+str(materialSpecular[1])+" "+str(materialSpecular[2])+"\r\n")

    file2.write("d 1.0\r\n")
    file2.write("Illum 2\r\n")
    file2.write("map_Kd "+filename+"\r\n") #for map_Kd



    file2.close()

MTLFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
mesh = pm.ls(g=True)[0]
U,V = mesh.getUVs()
```

This is querying all of the geometry in the scene and returning the first object, but you should be operating on the current mesh in the iteration.  I think what you want is:

```
U,V = p.getUVs()
```

Also, you should probably consider adding an argument to `meshFile()` rather than relying on a variable in the global scope.